# How to implement score ranking

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `student` table (`sid`,`sname`), a course `table`(`cid`,`cname`) and a `sc` table (`sid`,`cid`,`score`).

How to rank students information and their total score orderd by total score, if the total score same, orderd by `cid`.

My current SQL as below:

```
SELECT s.Sname,ISNULL(SUM(ss.Score),0) 
FROM Student s 
LEFT JOIN SC ss 
    ON s.Sid=ss.Sid 
GROUP BY s.Sname 
ORDER BY SUM(ss.Score) DESC
```

Comment: Do you have any issues with the query you already have?

Comment: current query gives error...Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you may use the `rank` in your query. Try the following:

```
SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(ss.Score) DESC) as rank, s.Sname, ISNULL(SUM(ss.Score),0) 
FROM Student s LEFT JOIN SC ss 
ON s.Sid = ss.Sid 
GROUP BY s.Sname 
ORDER BY SUM(ss.Score) DESC
```

See [working demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58462/3).